# Loading BPMN2 Processes at Runtime in Kogito

Tags: bpmn, kogito

I'm working with Kogito and I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically load BPMN2 processes at runtime. I want to be able to add or update BPMN2 processes without restarting or rebuilding the Kogito application.

I've looked through the documentation and examples, but I couldn't find a clear solution for this specific scenario. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve dynamic loading of BPMN2 processes in Kogito at runtime? Are there any specific APIs or configurations that need to be considered? Maybe dynamically mount a folder?

Additionally, if anyone has successfully implemented a similar feature, could you please share your approach or code snippets?

Thank you in advance for any help or pointers you can provide!

Comment: I've been exploring similar functionality in another BPMN engine, Flowable. In Flowable, there is a feature that allows users to deploy a new process definition through the REST API. This has been quite useful for dynamically updating processes without restarting the application: https://www.flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch02-GettingStarted#deploying-a-process-definition-1 

Has anyone come across a similar capability in Kogito?

Comment: Is this a production use case? Otherwise, you can rely on Quarkus devmode to do this. You can update the BPMN file that the application will refresh your process in runtime. But for production use cases, AFAIK, we don't support it. See more info about quarkus devmode here: https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#dev-mode

Comment: @RicardoZanini even in Quarkus dev mode, I haven't seen Kogito be able to digest a new bpmn on re-load.